# Is Graph API provide function to customize page tab?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tabs

I want to customize my page tab through API. Is Graph API provide function to customize page tab? If not, is there other third party api that can do this?

Comment: Customization is all about html

Comment: I want to customize like create new page tab, page tab content. Are there other third party api to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look into using one of the static html apps.  They certainly don't offer the flexibility of having your own app but if your content is simple they might be a solution.  A quick google search for "Facebook static html" should give you some options.

Answer (score 0):

Create a facebook app with a page tab implemented. Then add the app tab to your page.

In the facebook app, you can then do whatever you want to "customize your page tab".

Comment: thanks you very much for your reply. I have tried to create an app, Facebook not allow me to do. It's require me to verify my account by phone number or Credit card. I have tried many time with phone number, but it doesn't work. Is it Facebook problem? I have no credit card at all.

Comment: there are many people get problem in using phone number verification.  and if you don't get credit card, u can send your ID / passport to facebook directly.. I think they accept it too